d3d11 context map access problem 0x80070057
I put png file in my UI with stb_image and directx.
bool ImageR::LoadToMemory(const char* file_name)
{
    FILE* f = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (f == NULL)
        return false;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesizeinmem = (size_t)ftell(f);
    if (filesizeinmem == -1)
        return false;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fileinmem = IM_ALLOC(filesizeinmem);
    fread(fileinmem, 1, filesizeinmem, f);
    bool res= LoadFromMemory();
    EraseFile();
    return res;
}


bool ImageR::LoadFromMemory()
{
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
    image_data = stbi_load_from_memory((const unsigned char*)fileinmem, (int)filesizeinmem, &width, &height, NULL, 4);
    if (image_data == NULL)
        return false;
    return SetDevice();
}


bool ImageR::SetDevice()
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(desc));
    desc.Width = width;
    desc.Height = height;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

    pTexture = NULL;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subResource;
    subResource.pSysMem = image_data;
    subResource.SysMemPitch = desc.Width * 4;
    subResource.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    GGUI::pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, &subResource, &pTexture);
    // Create texture view
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&srvDesc, sizeof(srvDesc));
    srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = desc.MipLevels;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    GGUI::pd3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(pTexture, &srvDesc, &my_texture);
    pTexture->Release();
    stbi_image_free(image_data);
    return true;
}

it is okay it render my png on my UI but I want that change pixel in texture.
        DrawPoint(100, 100, 0xff0000ff);
        ImGui::Image(my_texture, ImVec2(UIW, UIH));

void ImageR::DrawPoint(int x, int y, UINT newColor) {

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    HRESULT hr = GGUI::pd3dDeviceContext->Map(pTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE, 0, &mappedResource);
    if (hr!=0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to map texture" <<std::hex<<": 0x"<<hr<<std::dec << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    _DrawPoint((unsigned char*)mappedResource.pData, ImVec2(x, y), ImVec2(UIW,UIH), 5,ImVec4(0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff));
    GGUI::pd3dDeviceContext->Unmap(pTexture, 0);
}


if I Use D3D11_MAP_WRITE I cant access to texture If I use D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE_DISCARD it blank bc it is refresh memory page I Think. What Should I do to change pixel to draw a point in texture.
note:Failed to map texture: 0x80070057
I tried so much flag.

Difficult to say from your code. Enabling and checking the debug layer should give you more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps otherwise you should post a reproducing project somewhere.

0x80070057 means Invalid Arguments. What is the type of pTexture?
